# Importing Qt Objects into Java - How?

Tags: java, qt-jambi

I wish to use the Qt GUI framework in my java program.
I've downloaded and installed the QJambi executable, which has made a lovely directory at C:\qtjambi-4.7.1.

I can't for the life of me, figure out how to actually import the Qt API into my java program.
The Qt Jambi wikipedia page [wikipedia page on Qt Jambi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_Jambi) gives a brief example, with the import statement `import com.trolltech.qt.gui.*;`, which does not work in my program.

This is obviously because my program can't find the appropriate files; neither can I!
I'm assuming I must have certain files from the Qt Jambi API in my program directory, but I'm not sure which!

So which files should I put where so that I can use the Qt Jambi API?
(I wish to wrap my program as an executable when deploying)

Thanks!

(Sorry for such a rookie problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using eclipse? You have to set the jar file (presumably there's a library jar file somewhere inside the qtjambi directory) on your classpath.

Comment: Added it to my class path in Eclipse. My code runs.  Not entirely sure over the complications of distributing my code now, but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.